# Connecting to Snowflake without specifying password using connectors

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using .net and python connectors to connect to Snowflake.
However, I have to either specify user/password to authenticate via Snowflake or via okta.
Is there a way I can do this without specifying password? Basically, if you are running this as a process on server (.net or python) I want dont want to keep password in config files etc.
Prefer to use something like below which uses IWA (Integrated Windows Authentication) but didnt see such option in Snowflake documentation:

https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Directory/Configuring_Agentless_SSO.htm

Answer (score -1):

You can setup an RSA key pair instead of specifying a username and password. It's pretty straight forward if you follow their documentation.

From their documentation:

> Snowflake supports using key pair authentication rather than the
> typical username/password authentication. This authentication method
> requires a 2048-bit (minimum) RSA key pair. Generate the PEM (Privacy
> Enhanced Mail) public-private key pair using OpenSSL. The public key
> is assigned to the Snowflake user who will use the Snowflake client.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-key-pair-authentication

If you want to use username/password but don't want to store them, I use the Snowflake python library through Databricks and store my credentials in Azure Key Vault so they aren't stored in my code.

Comment: thanks, I was going to give it a try. However, you still to maintain private key (and/or passphrase) somewhere. It will be ideal if you can use the credentials of logged in user to connect to snowflake.

Comment: @JayeshJain Updated my answer because I don't think I understood 100% initially.  But you should be able to store your credentials somewhere like Azure Key Vault or in Secret Server and then retrieve them from your python. We have people using both at our org, and using Okta on top of it.